# "Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters" in Scala

Tags: string, algorithm, scala

I've solved [Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/) problem using [sliding window](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/sliding-window-algorithm) technique :

```scala
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String): Int = {

  case class Acc(chars: Set[Char], left: Int, len: Int)
  s.zipWithIndex.scanLeft(Acc(Set(), 0, 0)) { case (acc, (c, right)) =>

    def moveLeftBoundary(chars: Set[Char], left: Int): (Set[Char], Int) =
      if (chars.contains(c)) moveLeftBoundary(chars - s(left), left + 1) else (chars, left)

    val (chars, left) = moveLeftBoundary(acc.chars, acc.left)
    Acc(chars + c, left, right - left + 1)

  }.map(_.len).max
}
```

The solution is accepted and not very long but looks a bit clumsy because of indices and the internal function. Could you suggest a simpler solution in Scala ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with internal functions nor indices. No reasonable workplace hold a competition for the point-free refactor of the week or sth. Your code is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't care fp or not for performance sensitive codes. Actually **pure fp style** code is **always slower** than no pure fp code in my experience.

Here we go:

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String): Int = {
    def rec(start: Int, end: Int, size: Int, visited: Array[Int]): Int = 
        if (end >= s.length) size
        else {
            val newStart = start.max(visited(s(end).toInt) + 1)
            visited(s(end).toInt) = end
            rec(newStart, end+1, size.max(end-newStart+1), visited)
        }

    rec(0, 0, 0, Array.fill(128)(-1))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I realized I should keep a mapping b/w visited chars and their indices (like your `visited` array) to remove my `moveLeftBoundary`, which makes my solution needlessly slow.

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75910698/521070) made me realize that I should keep a mapping between visited chars and their indices instead of just a set of visited chars as I did. So I can remove `moveLeftBoundary` to simplify the solution and improve the performance.

```scala
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String): Int = {

  case class Acc(left: Int, len: Int, visited: Map[Char, Int])

  s.zipWithIndex.scanLeft(Acc(left = 0, len = 0, Map())) { case (acc, (c, right)) =>
    val left = acc.visited.get(c).map(_ + 1.max(acc.left)).getOrElse(acc.left)
    val len = right - left + 1
    val visited = acc.visited + (c -> right)
    Acc(left, len, visited)
  }.map(_.len).max
}
```

This solution is shorter and more readable. The performance is better but still not great though.